# ember-data customs serializing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, serialization

Hello I am fairly new with ember and exploring it, I have been able to do a simple post to a resource, nevertheless  it render my object like this

```
{"person":{"atribute1":"jjj","atribute2":"jjj"}}
```

Is there a way to remove the "login" like a custom serializer, my endpoint work by passing an object in the form of

```
{"atribute1":"jjj","atribute2":"jjj"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You most likely will need to implement custom serializer for that purpose..

Comment: any ideas how to do something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find is override the createRecord, before I had

```
data[root] = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });
```

I removed the index of root and got this instead:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
                revision: 11,
                adapter : 'App.CustomAdapter'

        });

        App.CustomAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

                        createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
                            var root = this.rootForType(type);

                            var data = {};
                            data = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });

                            this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "POST", {
                              data: data,
                              context: this,
                              success: function(json) {
                                Ember.run(this, function(){
                                  if ( this.rootForType(type) == 'login' ) {
                                          return;
                                      }

                                  this.didCreateRecord(store, type, record, json);
                                });
                              },
                              error: function(xhr) {
                                //HERE to handle login operation failed
                                this.didError(store, type, record, xhr);
                              }
                            });
                        }

        });
```

Maybe a attribute like withRoot or something similar might be required.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, can you tell me where to add this in my code?

Comment: Sure I have edited, as you can see you add this by extending the RESTAdapter and override the createRecord please be aware that there are other method that behave similar this is only for POST operation when creating a Record. Also be aware that there is ticket opened https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/771 so you might want to follow up.

Comment: Is there a way to it for GET requests? to be able to use App.User.find()

Comment: You might be interesting in https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L241 In case of createRecord I modify the body to be posted GET request do not have body maybe you are refering on how to construct the url. find could be an interesting entry point for you to checkout.